# SQL CLR Aggregate incorrectly returning null

Tags: sql-server, aggregate-functions, sqlclr

I've added a user defined aggregate to my database for computing the product of a group.

The code was taken essentially verbatim from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/170061/Custom-Aggregates-in-SQL-Server).

I'm using the function to calculate the lifetime to date returns of financial instruments for which I have monthly return data.  The table looks something like this:

```
----------------------------------------------------------
| InstrumentId(int) | MonthEnd(datetime) | Return(float) |
----------------------------------------------------------
```

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT R1.InstrumentId,
       R1.MonthEnd,
       R1.MonthlyReturn,
       dbo.Product(1 + R2.MonthlyReturn) AS TotalReturn
FROM Returns R1
INNER JOIN Returns R2 ON  R2.InstrumentId = R1.InstrumentId 
                      AND R2.MonthEnd <= R1.MonthEnd
WHERE R1.InstrumentId BETWEEN 1 AND 50
GROUP BY R1.InstrumentId, R1.MonthEnd, R1.MonthlyReturn
ORDER BY R1.InstrumentId, R1.MonthEnd
```

The query works fine when I have only a few instruments, but adding certain instruments causes every result to be NULL.  When I execute the query with OPTION(MAXDOP 1) the results are fine.

Does anyone know what's causing the issue?

EDIT:
Forgot to mention that I'm running SQL Server 2012 and the aggregate targets .NET 4.5

Comment: "essentially verbatim" could hide a multitude of sins - are you able to elaborate on places where there are differences?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I've been using EXP(SUM(LOG(...))) to calculate product and it ignores nulls so I changed the product to ignore nulls as well.  I've also tried the code with no changes and it's still causing the same errors.

Comment: How have you changed it to ignore nulls? Have you just changed `IsInvariantToNulls` or have you made changes inside `Accumulate`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the modifications I would make to the Product aggregate if I wanted it to ignore `NULL`s.

Change the attribute:

```cs
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlUserDefinedAggregate(
   Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.Format.Native,
   IsInvariantToDuplicates = false,
   IsInvariantToNulls = true,      // receiving a NULL value will be ignored
   IsInvariantToOrder = true,
   IsNullIfEmpty = true,
   Name = "Product"
)]
```

Change `Accumulate`:

```cs
 public void Accumulate(System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDouble number) {
  if (!this.HasValue && !number.IsNull) { //Don't know if we'll be passed a NULL, but protect ourselves nonetheless
     this.Result = number;
  } else if (number.IsNull) {
     return; //Avoid setting HasValue
  } else {
     this.Result = System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDouble.Multiply(this.Result, number);
  }
  this.HasValue = true;
}
```

Change `Merge`:

```cs
public void Merge(Product group) {
  if (group.HasValue) {
    if(this.HasValue) {
     this.Result = System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDouble.Multiply
            (this.Result, group.Result);
    } else { //We may never have had our own value set
     this.Result = group.Result;
     this.HasValue = true;
    }
  }
}
```

I'm not sure if the change to `Merge` is truly needed, but I'd do it for safety's sake.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks.  I guess there's something wrong with the Merge function in the page I linked to since that was returning nulls when run over groups without nulls.

Comment: @willwpan - the theory I came up with was that it might parallelise the plan and create one instance per processor. But it a) Never knows if some of those instances will ever be passed a non-NULL value, and b) Doesn't know which ones to merge into - so it's possible that an instance is created, never receives any calls to `Accumulate` and then has `Merge` called on it.

Answer (score 0):

If `1 + R2.MonthlyReturn` is positive, I would considered use of `exp(sum(log(...)))` equivalent:

```
SELECT R1.InstrumentId,
       R1.MonthEnd,
       R1.MonthlyReturn,
       EXP(SUM(LOG(1 + R2.MonthlyReturn))) AS TotalReturn
FROM Returns R1
INNER JOIN Returns R2 ON  R2.InstrumentId = R1.InstrumentId 
                      AND R2.MonthEnd <= R1.MonthEnd
WHERE R1.InstrumentId BETWEEN 1 AND 50
GROUP BY R1.InstrumentId, R1.MonthEnd, R1.MonthlyReturn
ORDER BY R1.InstrumentId, R1.MonthEnd
```

Comment: I have been using EXP(SUM(LOG(...))) previously but I was hoping to add more custom aggregates in the future.  Given that even this simple one is causing errors (and that they can't be used in window functions yet), I'm hesitant to continue.

Comment: Be relied on built-in capabilities until it is absolutely impossible to live wihtout CLR functions perhaps is not a bad strategy.